# How does one determine the number of concurrent users that a web application can handle?

Tags: webserver

As far as I know, the Apache web server handles multiple requests through a combination of multiprocessing and multi-threading. Want I want to know is, for a PHP application running a web server, is it just Apache that decides the number of concurrent users it can handle, or does that also depend on the PHP application? If it is Apache, then to what extent does it control this?

Comment: Yes load testing questions definitely do not belong here

Comment: There are application-specific points to this question that equally belong on Stack Overflow

Answer (score 0):

It depends on both the web server and the application.

In general, one of the two will turn out to be the bottleneck that will limit the number of concurrent users. In my experience, it is *usually* the application which is the bottleneck, i.e. Apache can easily handle more requests than the application can handle.

Note: There may also be OS-specific limitations, e.g. to the number of network connections, the amount of available memory or the total number of threads/processes.